# need help for using selected item from listview as a variable on sql query

Tags: c#

think there is a problem at
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", listView1.SelectedItems ); 
anybody have idea for that??

```
 private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(tools.ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Employees",cnn);
        cnn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
            lvi.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
            lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["LastName"].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
        cnn.Close();
    }

    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(tools.ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select EmployeeId,BirthDate from Employees where FirstName = @name  ",cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", listView1.SelectedItems );
        cnn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Id= "+dr["EmployeeID"].ToString() + "\nBirth Date= "+dr["BirthDate"].ToString());
        }
        cnn.Close();
    }
```

thanks

Comment: Wel what is the type of the selected item. And are you aware that you are trying to pass in SelectedItems which is a collection of items not just one? I think what you may want is SelectedItem singular

Comment: are you sure listView1.SelectedItems is the correct data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need to change.

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(tools.ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select EmployeeId,BirthDate from Employees where FirstName = @name  ",cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text );
        cnn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Id= "+dr["EmployeeID"].ToString() + "\nBirth Date= "+dr["BirthDate"].ToString());
        }
        cnn.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: yes i want to get name from listview and than i want to get name's id and birth date from db. there 1 table on the db and query is working. but  i cant use selected item on listview..

Comment: its windows form.and its working with
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", listView1.SelectedItem[0].Text );
 but only 1 time for second time it gives me error like this
InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.

Comment: i debug it and im sorry i type it wrong when i write listView1.SelectedItem its not workng it said ..does not contain any definiton for selecteditem.
it works ..SelectedItems[0].Text and works only 1 time and for second time it gives error which says ArgumentOutofrange exeption was handled. InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'

Comment: YEs finally it works thanks:)and putting"if(listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)" line to the top is great idea cuz i try to put it  just before the "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);" Anyway thansk again:)

Comment: no problem. Mark the answer as solved and we can delete all these comments to keep the QA clean

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine selected items is a collection, try the selected item from the collection.